# Convert standard Array into columns in Snowflake

Tags: arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, iot

I have standard sensor data coming into Snowflake. Part of it is an array, I a trying to get this array into columns. To do so, I managed to get the array into a separate VARIANT column first, that looks like the one below. Does anyone know how to get this Variant column broken up into individual columns according to the key-value pairs?

```
Table name: Sensordata
Column name: rx_metadata
Data type: variant
```

```
[
  {
    "channel_index": 7,
    "channel_rssi": -87,
    "frequency_offset": "-6212",
    "gateway_ids": {
    "eui": "A84041FFxxx",
    "gateway_id": "xxx"
    },
    "rssi": -87,
    "snr": 7,
    "timestamp": 1825185681,
    "uplink_token": "Ch4KHAoQc3RyYXRpZnktdGVzdC12MRIxxx"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few steps, your outer object is an array `[` `]` so if you have only a known amount ( aka one) of entries you can just directly access it.

```
select parse_json('[1]') as a
    ,a[0] as inside;
```

| A | INSIDE |
| --- | --- |
| [ 1 ] | 1 |

Or if you have an unspecified count of objects, you can use FLATTEN to unroll the values into rows:

```
select f.value::number as val 
from table (flatten(input=>parse_json('[1,2,3]')))f
```

| VAL |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Then after that you have an Object, that you can again directly access if you parameters are known

```
select f.value:a::number as val 
from table (flatten(input=>parse_json('[{"a":1},{"a":2},{"a":3}]')))f
```

| VAL |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Or if you have an arbitrary number of properties per object you can flatten those as well:

```
select o.key, o.value
from table (flatten(input=>parse_json('[{"a":1},{"a":2},{"a":3}]')))f
    ,table (flatten(input=>f.value)) o
```

| KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |

Thus the last way for you data:

```
select o.key, o.value
from Sensordata, table (flatten(input=>rx_metadata))f
    ,table (flatten(input=>f.value)) o
```

gives:

| KEY | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| channel_index | 7 |
| channel_rssi | -87 |
| frequency_offset | "-6212" |
| gateway_ids | { "eui": "A84041FFxxx", "gateway_id": "xxx" } |
| rssi | -87 |
| snr | 7 |
| timestamp | 1825185681 |
| uplink_token | "Ch4KHAoQc3RyYXRpZnktdGVzdC12MRIxxx" |

but you could unpack each objects, from the array with:

```
select 
    f.value:channel_index,
    f.value:channel_rssi,
    f.value:frequency_offset,
    f.value:gateway_ids:eui,
    f.value:gateway_ids:gateway_id,
    f.value:rssi,
    f.value:snr,
    f.value:timestamp,
    f.value:uplink_token
from Sensordata, table (flatten(input=>rx_metadata))f
```

| F.VALUE:CHANNEL_INDEX | F.VALUE:CHANNEL_RSSI | F.VALUE:FREQUENCY_OFFSET | F.VALUE:GATEWAY_IDS:EUI | F.VALUE:GATEWAY_IDS:GATEWAY_ID | F.VALUE:RSSI | F.VALUE:SNR | F.VALUE:TIMESTAMP | F.VALUE:UPLINK_TOKEN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | -87 | "-6212" | "A84041FFxxx" | "xxx" | -87 | 7 | 1825185681 | "Ch4KHAoQc3RyYXRpZnktdGVzdC12MRIxxx" |

but you also could use, directly access the elements of a single sized array:

```
select 
    rx_metadata[0]:channel_index,
    rx_metadata[0]:channel_rssi,
    rx_metadata[0]:frequency_offset,
    rx_metadata[0]:gateway_ids:eui,
    rx_metadata[0]:gateway_ids:gateway_id,
    rx_metadata[0]:rssi,
    rx_metadata[0]:snr,
    rx_metadata[0]:timestamp,
    rx_metadata[0]:uplink_token
from Sensordata
```

To get the same results. It all depends on things that have not been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten the structure and then retrieve value from it.

Replace your table column inside CTE -

```
with data_cte as (
select parse_json('[ { "channel_index": 7,
"channel_rssi": -87,
"frequency_offset": "-6212",
"gateway_ids": { "eui": "A84041FFxxx", "gateway_id": "xxx" },
"rssi": -87,
"snr": 7,
"timestamp": 1825185681,
"uplink_token": "Ch4KHAoQc3RyYXRpZnktdGVzdC12MRIxxx" } ]') as val
)
// Add column list as needed
select value:"channel_index" as channel_index,
value:"channel_rssi" as channel_rssi,
value:"frequency_offset" as frequency_offset
from data_cte, lateral flatten(input=>val);
+---------------+--------------+------------------+
| CHANNEL_INDEX | CHANNEL_RSSI | FREQUENCY_OFFSET |
|---------------+--------------+------------------|
| 7             | -87          | "-6212"          |
+---------------+--------------+------------------+
```